# Ajax-запрос с processData = false

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Отправляю AJAX-запрос с параметром `processData = false`:

```
var params = {};
params = ...
jQuery.ajax({
    url: АДРЕС СКРИПТА,
    async: false,
    type: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    data: {'params': params},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {...},
});
```

А на сервере получить эти параметры не могу: `echo $_POST['params'];` выдает `undefined index "params"`. Думаю, это из-за `processData`, - массив параметров не преобразуется в удобный для PHP вид. Как быть в таком случае?

В запросе передается несколько данных, причем, как обычные параметры, так и файл. Эту настройку поставил именно из-за файла, так как без нее возникали другие ошибки.

---

Массив параметров содержит следующие элементы:

- id материала
- тип материала
- файл

Первые 2 параметра берутся из скрытого input'а на странице, а последний - в событии `change` fileinput'а (где, в общем, и вызывается AJAX-запрос) берется следующим образом:

```
function loadFile(element) {
    var file = this.files[0];
    ...
}
```

Далее все это записывается в массив:

```
var params = {};
params.matId = jQuery(...).attr('data-id');
params.matType = jQuery(...).attr('data-type');
params.file = file;
```

Comment: А можно показать прям вашу форму `html` и как params образуются

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, добавил в вопрос.

Comment: Стоп. Если это всё поля формы. То почему сразу бы не послать форму со всеми полями? а ля `var formData = new FormData($('#data')[0]);`  а в дата `data: formData,`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, это не поля формы. `Input` - просто кнопка "Загрузить файл", а остальные данные берутся из совсем другого места страницы. Конвертировать `file` в `formData` пытался, но если отправлять просто так - возникают ошибки (как я понял, из-за попытки JS конвертации этого объекта в строку). Если в этом случае отключить параметр `processData`, то возникает описанная выше проблема - когда просто не могу получить данные на сервере. Пустой массив `$_POST`.

Comment: а как же `Первые 2 параметра берутся из скрытого input'а на странице, а последний - в событии change fileinput'а` ? почему бы не обернуть это в форму и при сабмите не сделать аякс и то что я написал?.... а так... в любом случае вам придется создавать объект `FormData` и наполнять его поля данными.... щас попробую описать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых сразу напишу, что в запросе не хватает `contentType: false`, чтобы `jquery` не устанавливал `contentType`.

Далее по теме.
Для отсыла `multipart/form-data` с файлами на сервер необходимо использовать объект `FormData`.

Объект **FormData** позволяет составить набор пар ключ/значение для отправки при помощи **XMLHttpRequest**. Это, в первую очередь, предназначено для отправки данных форм, но вы можете использовать этот объект независимо от форм, тогда передаваемые данные будут в том же формате, что и при обычной отправке формы с enctype="multipart/form-dat

Подробнее о нем написано в [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects).

Итак, все необходимые данные, включая файлы нужно поместить в `FormData` парой ключ-значение.

```
var formData= new FormData();
formData.append('matId', 123);
formData.append('matType', "freak");
formData.append('file', files[0]);
```

И его уже передавать в аякс `data: formData`

Более наглядно:

```js
var files;

$('input[type=file]').on('change', prepareUpload);

function prepareUpload(event) {
  files = event.target.files;
}


// Отсыл данных на сервер
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function() {
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('matId', $('#test').data('id'));
  formData.append('matType', $('#test').data('type'));
  formData.append('file', files[0]);

  $.ajax({
    url: 'serverFile.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,

    success: function(data) {
      // do smth.   
    },
  });

  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="matId" data-id="123" data-type="hello" id="test">Image:
<input name="displayImg" type="file" />
<input type="Button" value="Submit" id="submit">
```

На сервере, делать что угодно:

```
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
```

Примеры реализации можно еще посмотреть [Здесь](http://true-coder.ru/php/ispolzovanie-obekta-formdata-dlya-zagruzki-fajlov.html) 
и
[Тут](http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax) (в случае нескольких файлов например)

Comment: спасибо, теперь все получилось. Как оказалось, проблема была в `data: {'params': params}`. Заменил на `data: params` (`params` - тот же `formData`), как у вас, и данные на сервере удалось получить.